# too many characters in character literal in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Facing difficulties: 
    **i'm looking for popup window for chat application in asp.net-c#**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
         sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>function Open() {"); 
         sb.Append(string.Format("window.open('Chat.aspx?rid={0}'",lstRooms.SelectedValue));
         sb.Append(, 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500'");return false;"); 
         sb.Append("}</script>");
```

here is

```
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock")) 
    {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock", sb.ToString()); 
    }

    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock")) 
    {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock", sb.ToString()); 
    }
```

i got error...**too many characters in character literal**...in this line

```
sb.Append(, 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500'");return false;");
```

thnks for guidence

i updated my question as above....plz help me

Comment: is this will helps you ...http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/372479/Multiple-Popup-windows-in-asp-net-using-javascript

Comment: i have developed it with using AJAX in asp.net.....i didn't got you ?

Comment: hiee all, i updated my thread so you can easily understand what i'm trying to do !! hope, u all help me.... thnks

Comment: thnks MUG4N sir for your instant helps....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a very easy and nice tutorial for popup with asp.net and ajax:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/modalpopup/launching-a-modal-popup-window-from-server-code-cs

Hope it helps you.

Greetings

**UPDATE:**

this code is tested and works fine:

HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="JavaScript:Open()" Text="Button" />
```

C#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>function Open() {");
            sb.Append(string.Format("window.open('Chat.aspx?rid={0}'", lstRooms.selectedvalue));
            sb.Append(", 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500');return false;");
            sb.Append("}</script>");

            if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock"))
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock", sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Of course you have to add the OnClick Attribute to your html button and point to the Open() Method.

Comment: i updated my thread so you can understand what i mean to say. ? ?

Comment: sir thanks for quick reply, but i got error **too many characters in character literal**.... as u can see in my updated threads...plz help me...

Comment: sir it works for me but i want to pass the **lstRooms.selectedvalue** instead of **passing index 5** **sb.Append(string.Format("window.open('Chat.aspx?rid={0}'", 5));
** in this line so how is it possible ??

Answer (score 1):

The error message points to a specific error: in C# you need to enclose strings in double quotes. Single quotes are used to mean a single character.

```
string mystring = "This is a test";
Console.WriteLine(mystring[0] == 'T'); // prints "True"
```

According to the compiler you tried to enclose a string in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

While linking the stylesheet/javascript/jquery avoid using runat="server" inside the tag.

If we include runat="server". It may also leads to the above mentioned error.