# too many characters in character literal with string builder in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, stringbuilder

i am using a string builder as follow...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {       
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
    sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>function Open() {"); 
    sb.Append(string.Format("window.open('Chat.aspx?rid={0}'",lstRooms.SelectedValue));
    sb.Append(, 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500'");return false;"); 
    sb.Append("}</script>"); 

    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock")) 
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock", sb.ToString()); 
    }

    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock")) 
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSScriptBlock", sb.ToString()); 
    }

    lblFacultyNo.Text = Session["User_Id"].ToString();
    lblUserType.Text = Session["User_Type"].ToString();

    pnlChat.Visible = false;        
}
```

now i'm getting error in this line....

```
 sb.Append(, 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500'");return false;");
```

for which mistake i got this error plz help me to solved it out quickly......thnks

Comment: see my update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381931/too-many-characters-in-character-literal-in-asp-net-c-sharp/10382442#10382442

Comment: First of all, there's a syntax error - you can't call `Append` with no first parameter but comma.

Comment: @OferZelig - but the comma can be the first char in a string. Simply missing an opening quote.

Comment: yeahhh, thanks all of you for helping me...i solved out.....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax-colouring should guide you here. Your strings are malformed:

```
//sb.Append(,'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500'");return false;");     
sb.Append(", 'newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500'\");return false;");
```

At the end it's either

```
 right=500'\");return false;");
```

or

```
right=500');return false;");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use quotes, `"`, not apostrophe, `'` for your strings.

Comment: The `'` are for the JavaScript. He certainnly shouldn't rreplace them in bulk.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use ' for string literal where you should use ". ' are used for characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to put a double quote in there just before `return false`, you need to escape it - note the backslash I have added

```
sb.Append(",newwindow','toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,width=290,height=330,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=350,left=980,right=500'\");return false;");
```

However it doesn't look balanced - I don't see a matching double quote.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing " at the beginning of the 4th line